# Why i have error when install UDK2015?

Tags: visual-studio, development-environment, uefi

I want to install UEFI Development Kit, I downloaded stable release and do anything as described in manual. I Use `win8.1x64` and Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Uodate 5.

When I execute BUILD command I get this log.

```
 Building ... c:\efi\udk2015\MdeModulePkg\Universal\HiiResourcesSampleDxe\HiiReso
    urcesSampleDxe.inf [X64]
            "GenFw" -o c:\efi\udk2015\Build\MdeModule\RELEASE_VS2013x86\X64\MdeModul
    ePkg\Universal\HiiResourcesSampleDxe\HiiResourcesSampleDxe\OUTPUT\HiiResourcesSa
    mplehii.rc -g D49D2EB0-44D5-4621-9FD6-1A92C9109B99 --hiipackage c:\efi\udk2015\B
    uild\MdeModule\RELEASE_VS2013x86\X64\MdeModulePkg\Universal\HiiResourcesSampleDx
    e\HiiResourcesSampleDxe\OUTPUT\Sample.hpk  c:\efi\udk2015\Build\MdeModule\RELEAS
    E_VS2013x86\X64\MdeModulePkg\Universal\HiiResourcesSampleDxe\HiiResourcesSampleD
    xe\OUTPUT\HiiResourcesSampleStrDefs.hpk
            "c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x64\rc.exe" /Foc:\efi\udk20
    15\Build\MdeModule\RELEASE_VS2013x86\X64\MdeModulePkg\Universal\HiiResourcesSamp
    leDxe\HiiResourcesSampleDxe\OUTPUT\HiiResourcesSamplehii.lib c:\efi\udk2015\Buil
    d\MdeModule\RELEASE_VS2013x86\X64\MdeModulePkg\Universal\HiiResourcesSampleDxe\H
    iiResourcesSampleDxe\OUTPUT\HiiResourcesSamplehii.rc
    "c:\Program" не является внутренней или внешней
    командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x64\rc.
    exe' : return code '0x1'
    Stop.


    build...
     : error 7000: Failed to execute command
            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Vc\bin\nmake.exe /no
    logo tbuild [c:\efi\udk2015\Build\MdeModule\RELEASE_VS2013x86\X64\MdeModulePkg\U
    niversal\HiiResourcesSampleDxe\HiiResourcesSampleDxe]


    build...
     : error F002: Failed to build module
            c:\efi\udk2015\MdeModulePkg\Universal\HiiResourcesSampleDxe\HiiResources
    SampleDxe.inf [X64, VS2013x86, RELEASE]
```

Comment: Please read [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your post with more information, sample code, and the steps you have taken so far. This information will make it more likely that someone can help you.

Comment: Also, a translation of the error message would probably substantially increase the likelihood of a response.

Comment: Check that "c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x64\rc.exe" is present and working.

Comment: CodeRush! You are great, and i try to build you CrScreenshotDxe from habrahabr..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just check rc.exe

In my case, there wasn't rc.exe

download sdk again

Comment: Maybe add the link you used to download `rc.exe`...?